# @ngtools/webpack: missing app.module.ngfactory

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I am trying to use the [@ngtools/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) plugin to create an AoT version of my Angular 4 app within webpack 2, but I am having difficulty understanding what this plugin produces.

In particular, I have a `main.aot.ts` entry point in my webpack for AoT, which looks like this:

```
// main.aot.ts
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../compiled/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';
const platform = platformBrowser();

platform.bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

and an extract of my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
if (envOptions.MODE === 'prod') {
    config.module.rules.push(
        {test: /\.ts$/, loader: '@ngtools/webpack'}
    );
    config.plugins.push(
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/tsconfig.json'),
            entryModule: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/src/app.module#AppModule')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            comments: false
        })
    );
}
```

Does this `@ngtools/webpack` plugin generate module files in the same way that the `ngc` compiler does, for inclusion in `main.aot.ts`? If not, how does it work? There aren't many examples of this on the web.

Comment: AOT is not acceptably documented and is not well defined. I imagine the plugin generates `app.module.ngfactory.ts` in memory using Webpack, just as a dynamic TypeScript transpiler generates JavaScript without producing files, except it generates TypeScript from TypeScript.

Comment: I am having similar issues, seems that some packages that I use are not AOT friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about `@ngtools/webpack` is that it creates those `.ngfactory` files in memory. Therefore there is no need to have any `main.aot.ts`.

`main.ts`:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

if (process.env.ENV === 'production') {
    enableProdMode();
} 
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

In your webpack  config:

```
var aotPlugin = new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
    entryModule: helpers.root('app', 'app.module#AppModule')
});

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: '@ngtools/webpack'
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
aotPlugin
]
```

Now, when you run the webpack the `@ngtools/webpack` will internally compile the Angular *out of the box*.
It's worth noting it's a good practice to have `@ngtools/webpack` only for production build because error messages it produces are bollocks.